# In a Jupyter Notebook in Watson Studio , how to refer to a file uploaded to the "assets"?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, watson-studio

in Watson Studio I am writing code in a Jupyter Notebook to use a Watson Visual Recognition custom model.
It works ok with external images.
I haven't been able yet to refer to an image I have uploaded to the Assets of my project. 
The url of the asset gets to a full page not the image only: 
https://dataplatform.ibm.com/projects/2f4b89d9-b93a-4c98-a327-9b863a467b7c/data-assets/ed16c385-e09e-4bcb-bfab-67ee864538e4/?context=data

Thank you

Comment: https://datascience.ibm.com/docs/content/analyze-data/load-and-access-data.html

Answer (score 3):

In Watson the asset files are saved in Cloud Object Store, or COS. You have to download the image from COS to the notebook server file system and then you can refer to the file in your notebook as a regular local file.

I use the cos api to get the files. https://github.com/IBM/ibm-cos-sdk-python.

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/cloud-object-storage/libraries/python.html#using-python

First, find out what your credentials are by

1. highlighting a notebook cell,
2. click Data menu,
3. select Files,
4. "Insert to Code"
5. credential.

Then you can download the file to your local disk storage using the API. For example, to download a file from COS:

```
# The following code contains the credentials for a file in your IBM Cloud Object Storage. 
# You might want to remove those credentials before you share your notebook.
credentials_1 = {
    'IBM_API_KEY_ID': '**************************************',
    'IAM_SERVICE_ID': 'iam-ServiceId-**************************',
    'ENDPOINT': 'https://s3-api.us-geo.objectstorage.service.networklayer.com',
    'IBM_AUTH_ENDPOINT': 'https://iam.ng.bluemix.net/oidc/token',
    'BUCKET': '********************************',
    'FILE': 'file.xlsx'
}

from ibm_botocore.client import Config
import ibm_boto3
def download_file_cos(credentials, local_file_name, key):  
    cos = ibm_boto3.client(service_name='s3',
    ibm_api_key_id=credentials['IBM_API_KEY_ID'],
    ibm_service_instance_id=credentials['IAM_SERVICE_ID'],
    ibm_auth_endpoint=credentials['IBM_AUTH_ENDPOINT'],
    config=Config(signature_version='oauth'),
    endpoint_url=credentials['ENDPOINT'])
    try:
        res=cos.download_file(Bucket=credentials['BUCKET'], Key=key, Filename=local_file_name)
    except Exception as e:
        print(Exception, e)
    else:
        print("Dowloaded:", key, 'from IBM COS to local:', local_file_name)
```

In a Notebook cell list directory contents:

```
%%script bash
ls -l


# to list all .png files in COS you can use a function like this:        
def list_objects(credentials):  
    cos = ibm_boto3.client(service_name='s3',
    ibm_api_key_id=credentials['IBM_API_KEY_ID'],
    ibm_service_instance_id=credentials['IAM_SERVICE_ID'],
    ibm_auth_endpoint=credentials['IBM_AUTH_ENDPOINT'],
    config=Config(signature_version='oauth'),
    endpoint_url=credentials['ENDPOINT'])
    return cos.list_objects(Bucket=credentials['BUCKET'])

response = list_objects(credentials_1)
for c in response['Contents']:
    if c['Key'].endswith('.png'):
        print(c['Key'], "last modified:", c['LastModified'])
```